# ServiceNotFoundException when making unit test?

Tags: php, symfony

I am following the tutorial here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html

I get a ServiceNotFoundException when running this line:

```
static::createClient();
```

The error comes from line 35 of

```
Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase.php
```

which is

```
$client = static::$kernal->getContainer()->get('test.client');
```

So I'm guessing that a service called test.client is missing. How can I make that service available? Or is something else broken?

Comment: Is 'test.client' included when you execute `$ php app/console debug:container -e test` ?

Comment: No, test.client is not there;{

Comment: Does your config_test.yml include a `test: ~` entry in the `framework` section? And does your app_test.php have this line: `$kernel = new AppKernel('test', true);`?

Comment: I don't know if it is a typo problem or not but you spelled $kernel with a `a`

Comment: @JulienBourdic I think is typo problem because this code comes from Symfony vendor :)

Comment: Thanks, the solution was to add test: ~ to the framework section of config_test.yml

Answer (score 0):

If you extend the WebTestCase class, you should be able to get a client using this code:

```
$client = static::createClient([]);
```

And if you're not able to get the kernel in any way, I used to create the following way:

```
$appKernel = new AppKernel('test', true);
$appKernel->boot();
$container = $appKernel->getContainer();
```